# How can I compare and valiudate value of two data picker with form item rules in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```html
            <Col className='input-forms' xs={24} md={3}>
                  <Form.Item label='start'>
                    {getFieldDecorator('start', {
                      rules: [
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: 'Start Date is required'
                        }
                      ]
                    })(
                      <DatePicker format='DD-MMM-YYYY' />
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
                <Col className='input-forms' xs={24} md={3}>
                  <Form.Item label='end'>
                    {getFieldDecorator('end', {
                      rules: [
                      { 
                      type: 'object', 
                      required: true, 
                      message: 'End Date is required' }]
                    })(
                      <DatePicker format='DD-MMM-YYYY'  />
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
```

I have two data picker which I want to validate them base on each other :
1:start should not be bigger than the end
2-should not be empty

I have no idea what should I implement invalidation?

also I am going to implement by rule

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form.Item
                    name="EndDatetime"
                    label="End Date & Time:"
                    rules={[
                      {
                        required: true,
                        message: "Please select product warranty type!",
                      },
                      {
                        validator: async (_, endDatetime) => {
                          var startDatetime =
                            formRef.current.getFieldValue("StartDatetime");
                          if (startDatetime!=null)
                            if (endDatetime <= startDatetime) {
                              return Promise.reject(
                                "Must be greater than Start Date & Time."
                              );
                            }
                        },
                      },
                    ]}
                  >
                    <DatePicker
                      format={"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"}
                      showTime
                      size="large"
                      className="w-100"
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
```